# WPF TreeView doesn't display arrows unless I modify styling during runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have an ObservableCollection that I populate during runtime which is bound to the TreeView. When the collection is updated, the root object of the collection appears in the TreeView without any way to expand it (see the first image).

I assumed this meant there was an issue with the binding, however, removing  TreeView.ItemCotainerStyle tag makes the arrow appear and everything works as intended (see the second image). This behaviour works in reverse too, if the style tag isn't in the view and I add it after the collection is updated then the arrows will appear.

The style tags aren't necessary for any function in my project to work, they're just leftover from an example I was working from.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding CompileMessages}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded"
                    Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                    Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                    Value="Normal" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:CompileMessagesDto}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{Binding Path=State}"
                                         Margin="3"
                                         Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Path}"
                           FontWeight="Normal"
                           Foreground="White"
                           FontSize="12"
                           Margin="3" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"
                           FontWeight="Normal"
                           FontSize="12"
                           Foreground="#ff8000"
                           Margin="3" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

```
public class CompileMessagesDto
{
    public string State { get; set; } = "";
    public string Path { get; set; } = "";
    public string Description { get; set; } = "";
    public string Parent { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<CompileMessagesDto> Children { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CompileMessagesDto>();
}
```

[TreeView before modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clRtb.png)

[TreeView after removing the style tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0l8M.png)

Initialising the collection with test values displays the arrows, it's only after the collection is modified during runtime that the TreeView behaves like this. I use [MaterialDesignInXaml](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML) if that helps at all.

## Edit (how the collection is updated)

It's definitely not the best way to do it but I loop through a collection of compiler messages and add them to the collection. I'm left with every object and a reference to their parent.

```
foreach (CompilerResultMessage message in messages)
{
    CompileMessagesDto compileMessage = new CompileMessagesDto { State = message.State.ToString(), Path = message.Path, Description = message.Description, Parent = parent };

    MessageCrawl(message.Messages, message.Path);

    CompileMessages.Add(compileMessage);
}
```

Then I set each object's children, and remove every object from the  collection that isn't the root object. Leaving the root with the tree of children in it.

```
List<CompileMessagesDto> removeItems = new List<CompileMessagesDto>();

foreach (CompileMessagesDto message in CompileMessages)
{
    message.Children = new ObservableCollection<CompileMessagesDto>(CompileMessages.Where(c => c.Parent == message.Path));

    if (message.Parent != "Root") { removeItems.Add(message); }
}

foreach (CompileMessagesDto message in removeItems)
{
    CompileMessages.Remove(message);
}
```

Comment: This is because your bindings in the `Style` throw errors. Your data models neither have a `IsExpanded` nor a `IsSelected` property.

Comment: @BionicCode I edited the question to show how the collection is updated. Even when the style is removed before running the solution, the TreeView doesn't display correctly. If I add the style back in (the same way I remove it in the images) then the arrows will appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the binding source `CompileMessagesDto.Children`:

```
message.Children = new ObservableCollection<CompileMessagesDto>(...);
```

Since `CompileMessagesDto` doesn't implement `INotifyProeprtyChanged` the `Binding` won't be able to recognize the property change.

General rule of data binding: the binding source must always implement it's properties as `DependencyProperty` if the source is a subclass of `DependencyObject`. Otherwise the source object must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
If you don't do this, your will create potential memory leaks.

To solve your problem either let `CompileMessagesDto` implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netcore-3.1#examples) and raise the `PropertyChanged` event from the `CompileMessagesDto.Children` property (recommended solution).

Alternatively keep the current `ObservableCollection` instance and use `Add` and `Remove` to modify it.

```
// Using for-statement allows to get rid of the 'removedItems' collection and the second foreach-statement (improve performance)
for (int index = CompileMessages.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
{
  CompileMessages
    .Where(c => c.Parent == message.Path)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(message.Children.Add);

  if (message.Parent != "Root") 
  { 
    CompileMessages.Remove(message); 
  }
}
```

Also note that your `Style` does throw errors. `CompileMessagesDto` does neither have a `IsExpanded` nor a `IsSelected` property.

Comment: Sorry for not making this clear in the original question. CompileMessages implements NotifyPropertyChanged when it's defined.

Comment: It's all about the `CompileMessagesDto.Children` property. `CompileMessages` is not the problem here.

Comment: My bad, I understand. Any idea why the UI seems to correct itself when the tags are modified in that case? I will implement what you've suggested now.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, sorry. As I said before when you apply the `Style` the setters generate errors, which stop your item bindings to work properly. When you remove the `Style` the errors are gone and the bindings can execute properly.

Comment: The binding engine tries to setup a fallback property changed notification system (because `CompileMessagesDto` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`). The binding errors cancel this setup. This fallback notification system creates static fields to store the binding source object. Static fields will never be garbage collected. Thus the fallback system creates a memory leak for each binding. Additionally this fallback system is extremely slow. Always use `DependencyProeprty` or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to avoid the fallback system.

Comment: Your solution worked, thanks for the code clean-up too.

Comment: For nothing. I'm happy I could help.